# How do you append a url as a query param value

Tags: url-routing, elixir, phoenix-framework, query-string

My website has a search form where someone can search a URL beginning with http:// like this:

```
https://www.google.com
```

which should then be encoded and appended as a query parameter value like this:

```
localhost:4000/api/https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com
```

When I run it (above) **locally, it works**, but when deployed (below):

`https://api.mysite.com/search/api/https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F`

=> returns 404.

If I type this in:

```
http://localhost:4000/api/https://www.google.com
```

I get this error:

```
Phoenix.Router.NoRouteError at GET /api/v1/https://www.google.com
no route found for GET /api/v1/https:/www.google.com (ExternalPing.Router)
```

I'm not sure if these are related.  What is the correct way to append a url as a query parameter value?

I have already tried encoding with URI.encode and URI.encode_www_form but they didn't resolve this

Comment: I think the answer here will work for you, even though they're not using routing (Check out the built-in function encodeURIComponent(str) and encodeURI(str).): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/encode-url-in-javascript

Comment: Are you sure `localhost:4000/api/https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com` doesn't work? It should work. Also, you can generate that using `URI.encode_www_form`: `"http://localhost:4000/" <> URI.encode_www_form("https://www.google.com") #=>
"http://localhost:4000/https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com"`.

Comment: localhost:4000/api/https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com does work it's when it's deployed it doesn't work, something like this:
https://api.mysite.com/search/api/https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F

Answer (score 0):

Now you haven't posted your server code, so I am just going to assume here.

I think the problem is that you didn't encode the second string, since it contains / in the url you have problems.

The url is:
`http://localhost:4000/api/https://www.google.com`

The server will interpret it wrong. So you are asking for a route called:

`/api/https:/`

With a parameter called `/www.google.com`

You need to encode the query string.

But again this is guessing since I have no idea how your server looks.

I just tried calling an endpoint at my iis server with a unencoded url as a parameter, and this is what it gave me back:

```
<Error>
    <Message>The request is invalid.</Message>
</Error>
```